# Trace norm of operators obtained by restricting the matrix of a trace class operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-algebras, operator-norms

Suppose $H$ is a Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $\{e_i\}_{i\in \mathbb N}$. To every operator $T$, we associate a infinite matrix $[T_{ij}]$, where $T_{ij}=\left<Te_j,e_i\right>$. We know that for any trace class operator $T$, the trace norm is $||T||_1=\operatorname{Tr}(|T|) $.

Q). Suppose $T$ is a trace class operator and $S$ is such that its matrix entries are either equal to the matrix entries of $T$ or they vanish (possibly at infinite number of points). Can I say that $||S||_1\leq ||T||_1$? If not, is there any finite upper bound to such $S$ obtained from $T$?

Comment: what is matrix $A$?

Comment: @SinaBaghal fixed. It was a mistake

Comment: If I remember well there is a counterexample in the paper The main triangle projection in matrix spaces and its applications by A. Pelczynski and S. Kwapien; Studia Math. 34 (1970), 43-67.

Comment: @DirkWerner Are they not talking about the rate of increase in norm of main triangle projections $T_n$  from M to M? How does it infer about this question?

Comment: Since the trace class norm and the operator norm are in duality, wouldn't your multiplier have the same norm in either case?

Comment: @DirkWerner Thanks, that was a nice reference. Also what do you think about the  projection $P_n:M\to M$ defined as $P_n(a)(i,j)=a(i,j)$ if $i>n , j>n$ and zero elsewhere? Can we conclude somehow from the growth of main triangle projection that $||P_n||\to 0$?

Comment: I mean to say, $S_n$ obtained by fixing $(S_n)_{ij}=T_{ij}$ for $i,j>n$ and zero elsewhere, does it follow that $||S_n||_1\to 0$?

Comment: This is clearly so when $T$ has a finite support and therefore also when $T$ does not have finite support. (The finitely supported matrices / operators are dense in the trace class; and $S_n= Q_n T Q_n$ where $Q_n$ is the orthogonal projection onto $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}^\perp$.)

Comment: @DirkWerner How do we see that finite support matrices are dense in trace class? I know that finite rank operators are dense in trace class but their matrices are not necessarily of finite support w.r.t to a basis. Also trace class can be identified with projective tensor product of Hilbert space.

Comment: `Also trace class can be identified with projective tensor product of Hilbert space': Once you know that, it follows that $H_0\otimes H_0$ is dense, with $H_0=$ linear span of the basis vectors $e_1, e_2, \dots$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's an algorithm for testing an ad-hoc conjecture $C$ about Hilbert space operators. :-)

0. Set up the runtime environment correctly by loading the information "Most conjectures are false" into short term memory.
1. Test $C$ against the zero and the identity operator.
2. Test $C$ against finite-dimensional diagonal matrices.
3. Test $C$ against multiplication operators on $\ell^2$ and $L^2$.
4. Test $C$ against the following $2 \times 2$-matrices:
   $$
     \begin{pmatrix}
       0 & 1 \\ 
       0 & 0
     \end{pmatrix},
     \quad 
     \begin{pmatrix}
       1 & 1 \\ 
       0 & 1
     \end{pmatrix},
     \quad 
     \begin{pmatrix}
       0 & 1 \\ 
       1 & 0
     \end{pmatrix},
     \quad 
     \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 1 \\ 
       -1 & 0
     \end{pmatrix},
     \quad 
     \begin{pmatrix}
       1 & 1 \\ 
       1 & 1
     \end{pmatrix}.
   $$
5. Test $C$ against simple modifications (appropriate to the setting of $C$) of the matrices from Step 4.
6. Write a computer programm to test $C$ against randomly generated $2 \times 2$-matrices; make sure to restrict the matrices that your random generator creates to the set of matrices that occur in $C$.
7. Repeat Step 6 with $3 \times 3$-matrices.
8. If you have not found a counterexample yet, there might be a reason to believe that $C$ holds.

Of course this should not be taken completely seriously - but often it works.
In my experience, for many ad-hoc conjectures the algorithm stops at Step 5 or earlier. The question from the OP adds another data point to this pattern:

The matrix
$$
  T = 
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 \\ 
    1 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}
$$
has trace norm $2$, but the matrix
$$
  S = 
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 \\ 
    1 & 0
  \end{pmatrix}
$$
has trace norm
$$
  \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} + \frac{\lvert 1 - \sqrt{5} \rvert}{2} = \sqrt{5} > 2.
$$

Comment: +2 if I could, for the answer, and the humour.

Comment: Also, note that taking suitably large direct sums of this counter-example shows that there is no hope of the conjecture "holding up to a constant" either (which the OP did ask about).

Comment: @MatthewDaws: Thanks for your comments! Yepp, I agree. The direct sum construction is also quite a useful way to built easy counterexamples. :-) I should probably add this to the list, together with a few typical infinite-dimensional candidates for counterexamples. But at the moment I urgently need to go to bed, so I'll postpone it to a moment when I'm really awake...

Comment: @JochenGlueck Thank you! that is a very nice algorithm :) .

Comment: I understand the direct sum argument. Now lets us fix a trace class operator $T$ and define $S_n$ for each $n$ entrywise as $(S_n)_{ij}=T_{ij}$ if $i,j>n$ and 0 else where. Now do you think Is it possible  in general to choose $n$ large enough such that $||S_n||_1$ is as small as we wish?